# Replace all values in tensor greater than zero

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `X`. If I just want to keep all values larger than zero I can use

`X = tf.nn.relu(X)`

But what do I do in the opposite case? I only can think of this solution:

`X = tf.multiply(-1.0, tf.nn.relu(tf.multiply(-1.0, X)))`

I wondered if there is a more sophisticated way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that `-X` is a better alternative to `tf.multiply(-1.0, X)`

Comment: @user1735003 Why is that the case? Because it is shorter? Or does it result in better performance?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to keep all the values less than zero. You can reverse the relu operation and use `tf.minimum(X, 0)` which "returns the min of x and y (i.e. x < y ? x : y) element-wise" and supports broadcasting, [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/minimum).